# Bluetooth module disconnect - arduino

Tags: module, bluetooth, arduino

I am working on a project on Arduino in which i require to blink LED when Bluetooth module is disconnected and switch off LED when it is connected.
Instead of LED, a buzzer can also be used.

Is there any code to do it

Comment: For behavior so specific, there probably is no existing code.  You might get some help on specific pieces ("how do I detect if *such-and-such-a-model* Bluetooth is connected to my Arduino" or "how would I use an Arduino to drive an LED or buzzer connected to certain  output?")

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar discussion going on [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=274474.0) also a demo code listed at the end. Below is some information to go ahead and program.

> I don't think Arduino can see the connection but it might be able to be told.
>
> The bluetooth is just a serial device at the other end of the cable, Arduino doesn't know what it is, doesn't know if it is doing anything, and doesn't care either. It can be programmed to listen for data but it wouldn't know if a deafening silence means nobody wants to say anything, or simply that bluetooth is disconnected.
>
> Bluetooth does know when it is disconnected, and typically flashes an LED to that effect. It therefore follows that the signal for the LED can sent to a pin on Arduino, which might be sufficient for you to do what you want to do.

There are several tutorials about Bluetooth by Arduino , check if you can tap any communication update in arduino and pass it to the out pin in arduino and display on LED.

Also this [link](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/mayooghgirish/arduino-bluetooth-basic-tutorial-d8b737) talks about controlling LED by Bluetooth.